# Is there a way to change what is stored on the "Go To Definition" stack in Visual Studio 2008 (and 2005)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, go-to-definition

Visual Studio 6 had the 'Go To Definition' (and 'Go To Declaration' functionality) just like Visual Studio 2005 & 2008.  Oh, actually, not *quite* like those two.

For some reason, not only are the 'Go To Definition' an 'Go To Declaration' actions added to their stack, but so are a lot of cursor movements, particularly 'Find' and 'Find Next' (maybe just those, but it seems like more than that).

Maybe this works for people who only discovered this feature since VS 2005 came out, but for those of us who used it before, this change has made the 'Go To Definition' stack just about unusable.  There's too much, plus I don't *care* to go back through my searches - if I did, I'd just search again!

Is there a setting somewhere to make it go back to the way it used to be?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's a keyboard mapping thing?  I'm using the Visual C# developer keyboard map now, and the Go To Definition stack seems to work okay.  CTRL-SHIFT-7 and 8 navigate as expected.  Are you using CTRL-minus?

Comment: Actually, I use Ctrl+* (The number pad asterisk).  It's a holdover from when I first started programming in VS 2!   I'll check my keyboard mapping and see if that addresses the issue.

Comment: In my keyboard mappings, I have the following:
View.BrowseNext : Ctrl + Shift + 1 (Global) 
View.BrowsePrevious : Ctrl + Shift + 2 (Global)
View.PopBrowseContext : Ctrl + Num * (Global)
It's this last one that I (used to) use all the time (before it got broken).
I tried the other two, but they seemed to have no effect.  I could see nothing taking place.

Comment: I'm using the Visual C# 2005 keyboard mapping scheme:

CTRL-SHIFT-7 = View.ForwardBrowseContent
CTRL-SHIFT-8 = View.PopBrowseContext